# Chrome Native Client toolchain missing 32-bit components

Tags: google-nativeclient

When I try to build the samples distributed with the Visual Studio add-in provided by Google, I receive the following error:

> The specified task executable location
>   "\nacl_sdk\pepper_44\toolchain\win_x86_newlib\bin\x86_32-nacl-gcc.exe" is invalid

The folder does exist, but none of the x86_32 versions of the tools exist. There are 64-bit versions and I can build with a 64-bit profile.

Where can I get the 32-bit versions of the compilers/utilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently distributed toolchain compilers are all moving to 64-bits to support bigger projects which run out of memory when building with 32-bit toolchains. There have been a few emails on that topic in [native-client-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/native-client-discuss), e.g. [this one](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/native-client-discuss/APi7t9PETp4/discussion).

The general consensus is that developers have 64-bit OSes on x86-64, so the change won't hinder them, and the bigger address space for builds helps quite a few of our developers. This further reduces build time (just one build), test time, and storage required.

Note that this doesn't affect targeting x86-32! A 64-bit build can still generate x86-32 code, the same way it can target ARM or MIPS.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't build the Nacl32 configuration, so I thought that meant I couldn't target x86-32.